# Gmail Gadget + Appscript Permissions in Chrome Webstore Listing

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-marketplace, chrome-web-store, gmail-contextual-gadgets

We have created a Gmail contextual gadget which allows users to upload emails to our system. This is deployed to the Chrome Web Store / Google Apps Marketplace and installed by a domain administrator to the users. To get the full raw email data including attachments we call an apps script from the gadget that uses the Gmail api to retrieve the data.

The first time the user tries to do this however they have to authorize the apps script against their Gmail account. Is there any way to include the permissions for the apps script in the marketplace listing so end users don't need to authorize the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible to do that.
Also beware your apps script might run into problems with many users concurrently running the script.

Comment: By problems do you mean exceeding quota limits? I was under the impression that the quotas listed at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas applied on a per user basis if the script is run as the user? Cheers

Comment: Yes api quotas will be ok, and this might not apply to user-auth scripts but ive also seen errors similar to "sorry the script has reached the maximum simultaneous execution quota"